# Strange behaviour from user

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've asked this question: [How to visualize an entire matrix when debugging Java with intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52383859)

A user has answered with something that I considered not useful and OT. Then I've downvoted the answer and replied politely in a comment to show why I wasn't satisfied with the answer. He replied with an aggressive comment, then deleted his answer and marked very fast my question as a duplicate of another question that seems to have nothing in common with mine...

To me, it seems a little revenge, because now my question is closed. So I'm asking if it's possible to reopen it now.

Comment: Ok I've edited the title. Hope you will analyze this strange behaviour and take necessary actions if needed.

Comment: Your question already has 3 out of 5 pending reopen votes. Can you give more details about vikingsteve’s answer and “aggressive” comment? You’ve (apparently) already taken the correct action by editing your question and explaining why it’s not a duplicate.

Comment: Ok! I don't remember exactly the deleted comment, but something like "if you use your brain etc..."... I suspect that he have also downvoted the other (surely more useful) answer. The act itself of signaling duplicate is at least superficial...

Comment: If what you want is to report the user for their comments and behavoir, better to do it by flagging your own post for moderator attention and explain the issue there.

Comment: _“If you use your brain […]”_ would definitely be flagged as “unfriendly or unkind” or even as “harassment, bigotry, or abuse”. If I remember correctly, both of these flags have consequences for the commenter.

Comment: Seems to me your question is double-barreled (1: how do I convert a matrix to a string, 2: how do I use a custom string conversion function to display a matrix in the debugger in this specific IDE) and one of those questions was answered perfectly fine by the user. You shouldn't see closure as a punishment if it's adequate. Imo it can either be classified as too broad or as a duplicate.

Comment: I know how to convert to a String. It seems clear to me that I'm only asking 2.

Comment: You haven't provided your solution for 1 in your question. How would one know you've already solved 1 from only reading your question?

Comment: Because I clearly never ask how to convert a matrix to a string. Read carefully the first phrase under the second picture.

Comment: ... You're missing the point entirely. The point is: the answer needs to solve 2 distinct problems, as you can clearly see in the answer you've provided: that starts with a function to convert a matrix to a string, doesn't it? Why would an answer need to contain that if you're not asking for it?

Comment: I don't know what question are you talking about

Comment: If the answer to your question were _"it can't be done, the only way to do that would be to convert the matrix into a string and store it into a real variable, which you can then see in the debugger inspectgor"_, would be be fine with duplicate target as it stands?

Comment: Related: *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*

Comment: Ignoring the nature of the question, if it was a 2-for-1 or not, it looks like nasty behavior to me. The exact comment was "So use your brain a little bit and replace the , with \n characters". Then the user, a gold badge holder on java, rage-closed the question as a dupe. If it was a dupe, why answer it in the first place? Fishing for points and when they didn't come, "no answers for you". Clear abuse of power.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't "strange" behavior.  Some users react very negatively to downvotes and/or criticism (constructive or otherwise), and don't like to be told they are wrong.  There's not much that can be done to fix that.

But as for how to address the situation depends on the behavior

- If the issue is just a rude or insulting comment, then flag the comment and move on.
- If the user escalates the situation, then the best course of action is to flag for moderator.

Since you can't flag a user directly, you need to flag a post.  Ideally you should select the most relevant post to the situation (the question or answer that is the catalyst for the behavior), but any of your or the user in question posts will work as long as you provide as a good summary of the situation.

1. Under the post, click "flag"
2. Select the "in need of moderator intervention" option
3. Provide as much detail as possible, but you have to be brief since the text most has a limited size (500 characters)

Other than having your flag marked as "helpful" (or "declined"), you'll probably never know what happened as moderator actions against users are not public.  The only thing you could see is if the user is suspended (assuming that level of punishment is needed) and you actively go look at the users profile while the suspension is in effect.

And lastly, if you feel a user is abusing their duplicate close powers, as you suggest in this case, you could wait for the moderator to handle your flag, or you could seek out community support to help reopen the question

- If you have 250 rep, you can vote to reopen you own question.  That will put it into the reopen review queue, where you will bring it attention to users with reopen privileges, but they won't necessarily be subject matter experts.  Those users may or may not choose to reopen the question
- If a chatroom exists for the tag, you can appeal for help there.  The room should hopefully have another gold badge user to reopen it, or enough users with close vote privilege to cast reopen votes.  Those users may tell you the duplicate is correct, but if they feel that the vote was cast incorrectly, they would be able to help you reopen the question.
- Last resort is to bring it to meta.  But make the post about reopening the question and not about the user who targeted you.  Again, you may be told the duplicate is correct or you could find sympathetic reopen voters.

Comment: Thanks. So I must change only the title?